# CheckboxTableViewer first column select all

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am currently developing a Wizard that will take me through a couple of steps.
On one of the WizardPages I want to have a dynamically filled table where the user selects some of the rows.
I am using a CheckboxTableViewer for this.
Currently it works well (including dynamic number of columns, etc.)
and the result looks like in the screenshot.[image: current behaviour]

My problem with this is that the first column spans over the column with the checkboxes. I would like to have the following behaviour:

- The first column header ("nodeAlias" in the screenshot) should start on top of the column, not above the checkboxes (so it needs to shift a bit to the right)
- I want to have a checkbox in the header above the checkboxes that performs a "select/deselect all"

My code that I am using in my wizard page (`extends WizardPage`) looks like this:

```
public class ShowResults extends WizardPage {
    private Table table;

    public ShowResults() {
        super("wizardPage");
        setTitle("Title");
        setDescription("Description");
    }

    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NULL);

        setControl(container);
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        CheckboxTableViewer checkboxTableViewer = CheckboxTableViewer.newCheckList(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        createColumns(checkboxTableViewer);
        table = checkboxTableViewer.getTable();
        table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(true); 

        checkboxTableViewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        checkboxTableViewer.setInput(getData()); // returns a list of Record-Objects
    }


    private void createColumns(CheckboxTableViewer checkboxTableViewer) {
        // get the required columns as list and act for each
        for(String columnName : getColumnNames()){
            // create a column for the first name
            TableViewerColumn colFirstName = new TableViewerColumn(checkboxTableViewer, SWT.NONE);
            colFirstName.getColumn().setWidth(150);
            colFirstName.getColumn().setText(columnName);
            colFirstName.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
              @Override
              public String getText(Object element) {
                Record r = (Record) element;
                return r.getValue(columnName);
              }
            });
        }

    }
```

I've not included the class definition for the `Record` as the displaying of information works anyway. (I guess it is not of importance for this problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take a look at Nebula grid widget? you can write your own CellRenderers for the column headers. See [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/nebula/org.eclipse.nebula.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.nebula.snippets/src/org/eclipse/nebula/snippets/grid)

Comment: this will fit all our hopes and dreams!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be not to use a header. Only act like you had one:

Keep a row as a fixed first element in your table, and add a unique setter to the element behind that special model. It should not only set it's own value but also other elements values in the list. It's other members will act as a static header.

Otherwise, if you manage to get the checkbox in the header, and it works on your platform (MacOS as it looks), it might still not work on an another.

Comment: I have tried to do something similar to what you suggest, but I didn't get very far. Could you add a (Pseudo-) code example?
I am curious how you would implement a "fixed first element".