# Check All checkbox in the header of a jface CheckboxTableViewer?

Tags: java, button, jface

I have a CheckboxTableViewer
I want to have a checkbox in the table header to check all rows
Is this possible with CheckboxTableViewer?

I have searched a lot of things and the only suggestion that i have found is to use Nebula grid widget, its not possible to do it with CheckboxTableViewer?

Comment: You can check this. This may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944765/checkboxtableviewer-first-column-select-all

Comment: You can check this. This may be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31944765/checkboxtableviewer-first-column-select-all

Comment: No it is not possible with CheckboxTableViewer